# Trying to get Material-UI clipped drawer to work in flex layout

Tags: material-ui, drawer

I started with the clipped drawer sample code and tried to build around it. When inserting components inside the sample  (i.e., replacing '{'You think water moves fast? You should see ice.'} with other content), the content is constrained by the height of the drawer. When trying to insert content outside of the sample , everything starts below the drawer.

Expected Behavior:  ability to place content anywhere around the drawer. I've got different components hiding/becoming visible based on drawer menu selections

I originally started with the permanent drawer example and everything worked just fine except I need the drawer positioned below the app bar.

Answer (score 6):

The layout consists of a flex container that contains the `Drawer` and main content area. The content area (`.appContent`) expands to fill the space to the right (or left) of the drawer. All of your content should be placed inside this element.

**Updated**: Fixed styles to work on IE 11

**The basic structure:**

```js
<div className={classes.root}>
  <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} />
  <Drawer 
    variant="permanent"
    className={classes.drawer}
    classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }} 
  />
  <main className={classes.appContent}>
    {/* Page content goes here */}
  </main>
</div>
```

**The styles**

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  // The main flex container for the app's layout. Its min-height
  // is set to `100vh` so it always fill the height of the screen.
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    minHeight: "100vh",
    zIndex: 1,
    position: "relative",
    overflow: "hidden",
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1
  },
  // Styles for the root `div` element in the `Drawer` component.
  drawer: {
    width: theme.layout.drawerWidth
  },
  // Styles for the `Paper` component rendered by `Drawer`.
  drawerPaper: {
    width: "inherit",
    paddingTop: 64  // equal to AppBar height (on desktop)
  },
  // Styles for the content area. It fills the available space
  // in the flex container to the right (or left) of the drawer.
  appContent: theme.mixins.gutters({
    // https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-17
    flex: '1 1 100%', // Updated to fix IE 11 issue
    maxWidth: "100%",
    paddingTop: 80,   // equal to AppBar height + 16px
    margin: '0 auto',
    // Set the max content width for large screens
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
      maxWidth: theme.breakpoints.values.lg,
    },
  })
```

**Live Examples (codesandbox)**

[Permanent Drawer - clipped below appbar](https://codesandbox.io/s/vmx7z4kx33?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FApp.js&view=editor)

[Permanent Drawer - full height](https://codesandbox.io/s/vm4r07mxn5?hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FApp.js&view=editor)

Comment: Luke, thanks for going above and beyond with this explanation and the code sample. Now that I see it in action its, it makes a lot of sense

Comment: Hey Luke thanks a lot for the code samples it was helpful. However, I have a fixed drawer component, and my appContent is still not filling the available space and is leaving white spaces on both left and right. I have used the exact same code as your first example so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. :(

Comment: @Annjawn, In the CodeSandbox  examples, `.appContent` has a `max-width` of `1200px` and `margin: 0 auto`. So on large screens the content area will be constrained to `1200px` and centered in the space to the right (or left) of the drawer. The `.root` element always fills the entire width of the viewport. If you remove the `max-width` from `.appContent`, it will should expand to the full width of the flex container (next to the drawer). Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hey @LukePeavey , thanks for the response. The real issue was a misconfiguration on my part for not using `MuiThemeProvider` correctly. Once I resolved that, the problem was gone.

Comment: @Annjawn Ok, glad you were able to fix the issue

Comment: @LukePeavey it looks like the Responsive breakpoints are not working very well in IE11. for example - the `theme.breakpoints.up("lg")` is making the content centered in Chrome but in IE it is overflowing to the right (with app bar in the left). Are you aware of anything that might be causing this? I can recreate the issue with your "Full Height Example". Also, this is specific to a wide screen desktop monitor that I am using and that most people in my company use and is happening only in IE.

Comment: @Annjawn I just tested the examples on IE 11 and I'm seeing the same problem on large screens. IE 11 has some [flexbox related bugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) that require specific workarounds. I will take a look at it later today and see if i can find a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first it seemed as if the issue was due to incompatibility of `<main>` tag with IE, but then replacing `<main>` with `<div>` also didn't resolve the issue. What made it work is setting the `maxWidth: '100%'` but then it completely messes up the layout (as in makes it look ugly).

Comment: Looks like FlexBug #2 is somewhat what is happening here and `max-width: 100%` is the work around.... but an ugly one :( and I am not sure how to use `box-sizing: border-box` with MUI.

Comment: @Annjawn The main issue was caused by [Flexbug #17](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-17).  I just updated the examples, and it looks like both are working in IE.

Comment: @LukePeavey Yes it did work very well. I had a `GridList` in the flex box and the `overflowY` had to be set to `visible` otherwise it was being clipped with scrollbar. But so far so good. Thank you so much for all the help :)

Comment: The react version of those codesandboxes are out of date, crashing the examples

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I created those a while ago, Im sure they need to be updated to work with latest version of material ui. I will fix today

Comment: @Quill Thanks for the heads up. I updated the examples to latest react version. They are working now